# How to programmatically extract all rectangle shapes from SVG file?

Tags: vector-graphics, java

I have a SVG which contains rectangles with other shapes. How can I extract all rectangle details(co-ordinates, height and width)? Find below svg details where I kept only one rectangle for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="301.36mm" height="174.36mm" viewBox="0 0 1139 659" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="bevel">
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="clip27">
                <path d="M-272.5,-2.5 L866.5,-2.5 L866.5,656.5 L-272.5,656.5 L-272.5,-2.5 z"/>
            </clipPath>
        </defs><g clip-path="url(#clip27)" fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="2" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,272.5,2.5)">
            <path d="M0,0 L110,0 L110,176 L0,176 L0,0 z" fill-rule="evenodd" vector-effect="none"/>
        </g>
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="clip34">
                <path d="M0,0 L112,0 L112,15 L0,15 L0,0 z"/>
            </clipPath>
        </defs><g clip-path="url(#clip34)" fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,271.07,180)">
            <text fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" font-family="Arial" font-size="10" font-style="normal" font-weight="400" stroke="none" textLength="109.859" x="1" xml:space="preserve" y="11">BoostDiagSlow_Release</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: If the shapes are defined by just a series of line drawing commands (go to point X, draw to point Y, etc), there's not a simple way to know what is a "rectangle". It would be better if you could get the author of the file to use some naming conventions to tell you which things are "rectangles".

Comment: Well, you could do this. Its not super practical though. As there are quite a bit of corner cases.